# Visual Studio 2008 (C# @ Verbatim) Fonts and Colors option

Tags: visual-studio-2008, fonts, colors, settings

I just read **[secretGeek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241/secretgeek)**'s fun post on **[8 ways to be a better programmer in 6 minutes](http://www.secretgeek.net/6min_program.asp)** and really liked the tip on making **hard-coded strings look ugly**.

When I tried to change the **Fonts and Colors** setting to do this in my copy of Visual Studio 2008 Professional, I found that the **String (C# @ Verbatim)** option was not in the **Display items** list. The option *is* listed in Visual C# Express 2008.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after a bit of experimentation, this worked for me.

SysInternals [regmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896652.aspx) showed that the **Font And Colors** options for VS2008 Pro are stored in the registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\FontAndColors
```

Deleting this and restarting Visual Studio caused the key to be rebuilt and restored the **String (C# @ Verbatim)** option.

The option is missing from the VS2005 Pro key too, so maybe that's why it never appeared in 2008.

Is Magenta over Lime too masochistic??